# A class called Clock

Tags: c++

I am required to create a class called Clock. In it, it needs a default constructor, a constructor that accepts seconds, and a constructor that accepts hours, minutes and seconds. It needs pubic member functions that set h/m/s, get h/m/s, increment/decrements seconds, adds any number of seconds. It needs private members that converts hms to sec, and vice versa.

There is a pre written code to implement my class.

The biggest error seems to be one that says:

expected unqualified-id before ‘void’

Thank you very much. I hope this isn't too much to read.

I cannot figure out what is giving me the error messages. I am new to c++, and what I have researched about the errors aren't helping.

```
#ifndef Clock
#define Clock



class Clock{

    private:

    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;

    int hms_to_sec() const;
    void sec_to_hms(int seconds);

    public:

    Clock();
    Clock(int seconds);
    Clock(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);


    void set_hour(int hours);
    void set_minute(int minutes);
    void set_second(int seconds);

    void add_seconds(int seconds);

    int get_hour() const;
    int get_minute() const;
    int get_second() const;

    void increment();
    void decrement();


};

#endif




#include "lab8Clock.h"



Clock::Clock(){
    hour=0;
    minute=0;
    second=0;
}

Clock::Clock(int seconds){
    if(seconds>=86400){
        hour=0;
        minute=0;
        second=0;
        return;
    }

    sec_to_hms(seconds);
}
Clock::Clock(int hours, int minutes, int seconds){


    if(hours<0 || minutes<0 || seconds<0){
        hour=00;
        minute=00;
        second=00;
        return;

    }
    if(hours>=24 || minutes>=60 || seconds>=60){
        hour=00;
        minute=00;
        second=00;
        return; 
    }
    hour=hours;
    minute=minutes;
    second=seconds;


}

void Clock::sec_to_hms(int seconds){
    int h=0, m=0, s=seconds;
    for(int i=0; i<=seconds; i++)
    {
        if(i%60==0&&i>0;){
            m++;
            s-=60;
        }
    }
    for(int j=0; j<=minutes; j++)
        if(j%60==0&&j>0){
            h++;
            m-=60;
        }
    hour=h;
    minute=m;
    second=s;

}

int Clock::hms_to_sec() const{
    int s;
    s+=(hour*3600);
    s+=(minute*60); 
    s+=second;
    return s;
}

void Clock::set_hour(int hours){
    if(hours>=24 || hours<0)
        return;

    hour=hours;
}
void Clock::set_minute(int minutes){
    if(minutes>=60 || minutes<0)
        return;

    minute=minutes;
}
void Clock::set_second(int seconds){
    if(seconds>=60 || seconds<0)
        return;

    second=seconds;
}

void Clock::add_seconds(int seconds){

    int s=seconds,m=0, h=0;
    int holder;
    if(seconds<0)
        return;


    if((second+=seconds)>86400)
        return;
    for(int k=0; k<seconds; k++){
        if(k%60==0 && k>0){
            m++;
            s-=60;

        } holder=m;
    }
    for(int k=0; k<holder; k++){
        if(k%60==0 && k>0){
            h++;
            m-=60;
        }
    }
    hour+=h;
    minute+=m;
    second+=s;
}


int Clock::get_hour() const{
    return hour;
}
int Clock::get_minute() const{
    return minute;
}
int Clock::get_second() const{
    return second;
}

void Clock::increment(){
    int i;
    i=hms_to_sec();
    if(i==86399){
        hour=0;
        minute=0;
        second=0;
        return;
    }
    add_seconds(1);
}
void Clock::decrement(){
    int i;
    if(i==0)
        return;

    second--;
}
```

Example of errors ("second, minute, hour" are the member variables of Clock):

```
In file included from lab8exa.cpp:12:0:

lab8Clock.h:19:8: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘void’
  Clock(void);
        ^~~~

lab8Clock.h:19:8: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘void’


lab8clock.cpp:59:2: error: ‘minute’ was not declared in this scope
  minute=m;
  ^~~~~~

lab8clock.cpp:59:2: note: suggested alternative: ‘int’
  minute=m;
  ^~~~~~


lab8clock.cpp:60:2: error: ‘second’ was not declared in this scope
  second=s;
  ^~~~~~


lab8clock.cpp: At global scope:
lab8clock.cpp:64:25: error: explicit qualification in declaration of ‘int hms_to_sec()’
 int Clock::hms_to_sec() const{
                         ^~~~~

lab8clock.cpp:64:25: error: non-member function ‘int hms_to_sec()’ cannot have cv-qualifier
```

lab8clock.cpp:141:23: error: explicit qualification in declaration of ‘void decrement()’
 void Clock::decrement(){
                       ^

Comment: It says the errors are in a file you didn’t include and it says on which line. Check the header file.

Comment: The errors appear to be due to a problem in the include file lab8clock.h and you have not provided a copy of that source code in your posting. Please add the source code that is in the file lab8clock.h by editing your post to include it.

Comment: @RichardChambers I have included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #endif in your header file is not correctly placed. #endif should be at the end of the header file after the declaration of the class.

Additionally, the #ifndefine Clock and #define Clock will create an error as its the exact name of the class. Change it to Clock__H__ or something like that.

Finally, in line 46 you have an extra ; in the if statment and 51 should me minute not minutes I believe. With these changes the code is compiling for me.

One final thing, before using s for

```
s+= ...
```

you need to set a value for s (s=0). For the += operator to work some value must already be in s